# Uploading Video on Amazon S3 - "too much to process! with exit code 137"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a video file to my amazon bucket. Below is a code that I am using to do so. I followed the [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileJava.html) on amazon documentation.

It starts and says "too much to process!" and exits with 137. Why is it failing to upload? The size of the video is only 80 MB.

```
    String existingBucketName = "***mybucket***";
    String keyName ="***myVideo.mov***";
    String filePath = "***/Users/myhomedir/Desktop/myVideo.mov***";

    TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    System.out.println("Hello");
    // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
    // so this call will return immediately.
    Upload upload = tm.upload(
            existingBucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));
    System.out.println("Hello2");

    try {
        // Or you can block and wait for the upload to finish
        upload.waitForCompletion();
        System.out.println("Upload complete.");
    } catch (AmazonClientException amazonClientException) {
        System.out.println("Unable to upload file, upload was aborted.");
        amazonClientException.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was my multipart resolver! I needed to increase the max in memory size.     multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(90971520);